Getting The resource could not be found when fetching content from sharepoint using graph api
this is the code:
import streamlit as st
import requests
import urllib

client_id = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
client_secret = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
tenant_id = 'YOUR_TENANT_ID'

site_id = "m365x36241825.sharepoint.com,2b7d320b-e002-4e09-a83c-769c46353838,3544db06-d815-4384-aea2-2da9910245aa"
file_path = "/sites/Contoso/Shared Documents/General/datastax.txt"

# Function to get access token
def get_access_token(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id):
    token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    token_data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    }
    token_r = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
    return token_r.json().get('access_token')

# Function to fetch file content
def fetch_file_content(token, site_id, file_path):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
    }
    # Encode the file path
    encoded_file_path = urllib.parse.quote(file_path)
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drive/root:{encoded_file_path}:/content"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print("URL:", url)
    return response


# List contents of the "General" folder
def list_folder_contents(token, site_id, folder_path):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
    }
    encoded_folder_path = urllib.parse.quote(folder_path)
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drive/root:{encoded_folder_path}:/children"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print("URL:", url)
    return response

# Folder path to the "General" folder
folder_path = "/sites/Contoso/Shared Documents/General"
token = get_access_token(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id)
response = list_folder_contents(token, site_id, folder_path)

if response.status_code == 200:
    items = response.json().get('value', [])
    for item in items:
        print(f"Name: {item['name']}, ID: {item['id']}, Type: {item['folder'] if 'folder' in item else 'file'}")
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.json()}")

# Streamlit app
st.title("SharePoint File Content")

token = get_access_token(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id)
response = fetch_file_content(token, site_id, file_path)
print("Token: ")
print(token)
if response.status_code == 200:
    file_content = response.content.decode('utf-8')  # Assuming it's a text file
    st.text(file_content)
else:
    st.error(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.json()}")

this code is giving me response: {'error': {'code': 'itemNotFound', 'message': 'The resource could not be found.'}}
while it is present in the sharepoint: https://m365x36241825.sharepoint.com/sites/Contoso/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FContoso%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral%2Fdatastax%2Etxt&viewid=30ac4a84%2D14e8%2D4f6e%2D86b4%2D6da6fa8830b3&parent=%2Fsites%2FContoso%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral
I have added all the permission in the azure portal.

I think that file_path and folder_path are wrong
file_path = "/sites/Contoso/Shared Documents/General/datastax.txt"
folder_path = "/sites/Contoso/Shared Documents/General"

You are calling the endpoint
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drive/root:{path}:/

drive/root points to site's default document library (Shared Documents), so file_path and folder_path should be relative paths
file_path = "/General/datastax.txt"
folder_path = "/General"

